# How to show the multiple paths between different points in google maps in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to show multiple paths between different points in google maps.I am using below code.I have also attached images here.

```
    public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{
         private GoogleMap mMap;


            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
                // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
                SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
            }


        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                mMap = googleMap;

                // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
                LatLng Madhapur = new LatLng(17, 78);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Madhapur));
                LatLng CyberTowers=new LatLng(17.4504,78.3811);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(CyberTowers));
                LatLng Kondapur=new LatLng(17.4622,78.3568);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Kondapur));
                mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().
                        add(Madhapur,
                                new LatLng(17.4504,78.3811),
                                new LatLng(17.4524, 78.3796),
                                Kondapur
                        )
                        .width(10)
                        .color(Color.BLUE));
      }
}
```

[image: Image attached to show exact requirement]

Comment: Can you explain more ? What do you mean "multiple path" ? For ex you have 3 location A B C. You want draw line from A to B, B to C, A to C ? or you want draw direction ?

Comment: I want to draw direction between multiple places.Multiple path means route direction.

Comment: i got it, please see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

1. Please get data from this api, with these parameter: origin (
   lat,long of source), destination(lat, long of destination), key(
   google api key)  http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json
2. Data which get from above api is a list of location from A to B. All
   you have to do is draw a list of dot from data. You will get a
       direction line from a to b

   final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
           JSONArray routeArray = json.getJSONArray("routes");
           JSONObject routes = routeArray.getJSONObject(0);
           JSONObject overviewPolylines = routes
                   .getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
           String encodedString = overviewPolylines.getString("points");

   ```
   JSONArray legArray =routes.getJSONArray("legs");
   JSONObject legs= legArray.getJSONObject(0);
   JSONObject distance =legs.getJSONObject("distance");
   String dis=distance.getString("text");
   RouteActivity.txtDistance.setText("("+dis+")");

   JSONObject duration =legs.getJSONObject("duration");
   String dur=duration.getString("text");
   RouteActivity.txtTime.setText(dur);

   List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(encodedString);

   PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true);
   for (int z = 0; z < list.size(); z++) {
       LatLng point = list.get(z);
       options.add(point);
   }
   mGoogleMap.addPolyline(options);
   ```

private static List decodePoly(String encoded) {

```
List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
int lat = 0, lng = 0;

while (index < len) {
    int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
    do {
        b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
        result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
        shift += 5;
    } while (b >= 0x20);
    int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
    lat += dlat;

    shift = 0;
    result = 0;
    do {
        b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
        result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
        shift += 5;
    } while (b >= 0x20);
    int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
    lng += dlng;

    LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
            (((double) lng / 1E5)));
    poly.add(p);
}

return poly;
```

}